# Lower bound on clique number

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, puzzle, graph-algorithm

What is the smallest clique number (that is maximum clique size) possible for a graph with n vertices and m edges? I was thinking of using Turan's theorem, but that just tells us an upper bound on the number of edges given the clique number. I've been stuck on this for days, and could use some help.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag appropriately.

Comment: not homework, but rather an exercise on one of those programming challenge sites

Comment: So you're passing the challenge on to SO?

Comment: only because i think its an interesting problem and i would like to finally know the answer

Comment: fair enough. what's the site where this question was originally posed?

Comment: Does "a graph" mean you have a fixed graph, or are you looking for an extreme example graph?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this question has a simple answer (as is often the case with Ramsey-esque problems), but here is an approach to get you started (I'm assuming this is homework and so I won't try to work it all the way out).

Assume the graph is connected (without this assumption, the problem only gets harder). Let `k` be the smallest clique number possible. The extreme cases are:

- If `n = m-1` (equivalently, the graph is a tree), then `k=2`.
- If `m = (n choose 2)` (equivalently, the graph is complete), then `k=n`.

From this one might reasonably infer that as `m` increases relative to `n`, `k` should also increase. Go with this idea and see where it takes you.

---

I worked out the numbers for small `n,m` and the results are not in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), though possibly I made a computational error (please let me know if you find one). Here are the numbers:

```
n\m | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
---------------------------
 1  | 1 - - - - - - - - - -
 2  | - 2 - - - - - - - - -
 3  | - - 2 3 - - - - - - -
 4  | - - - 2 2 3 4 - - - -
 5  | - - - - 2 2 2 3 3 4 5
 6  | - - - - - 2 2 2 2 2 3
```

Again, I'm assuming connected (at least `n-1` edges) and no loops (at most `(n choose 2)` edges).